# sessionStorage and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, session-storage, web-storage

I'm attempting to use Web Storage (sessionStorage in particular) to save an instance of a Google Map and markers thats being generated based on a user's Postal Code.

The functionality of this is:

1. User searches for 'store locations' with a postal code.
2. Map generates, with markers on each found location.
3. User clicks on a result/marker - linking to a 'store location landing page'.
4. User can return to search.
5. Their searched map with results/markers should remain.

Is this possible with sessionStorage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but sessionStorage is cleared out when the window is closed. If you want them to stay even when the window is closed, you should use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

To save data into sessionStorage, you'd use syntax like the following:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name_of_key', 'value_for_key');
```

For more help with sessionStorage, check out the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: Thanks @vemonus. I'll use sessionStorage as I don't need the data to persist if the window is closed... I'm not really sure how to save the actual map instance though... any ideas/examples? Thanks.

Comment: @WankChunk I don't *think* you could save the map, since web storage only stores strings. You could probably save coordinates from the map then rebuild the map based on them when they reloaded it. Another idea might be to create a custom URL based on the coordinates with a map instance and save *that* into sessionStorage.

Comment: Thanks @Vemonus, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: you would think Google Maps has some sort of functionality for this type of thing?

Comment: I ended up just saving my search term - and coords to session storage, then checking if that variable exists on page reload. Works amazing, thanks!

Comment: @WankChunk glad it helped